# How to improve the efficiency of the backtracking search in CSPs?

Tags: search, constraint-satisfaction-problems, efficiency, depth-first-search, uninformed-search

Backtracking search is the basic uninformed search algorithm for constraint satisfaction problems (CSPs). How could we improve the efficiency of the backtracking search in CSPs?

Comment: Backtracking algorithms can be improved by adding heuristics methods.
You could add filtering and ordering techniques.

Comment: @Cecelia - If you have an answer, can you please post it as an answer below instead of as a comment? Thank you!

Comment: This question may do better on or.stackexchange.com